# propertyIsEnumerable logs false for property detected within for..in

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand [Enumerability and ownership of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties). It says:

> Enumerable properties show up in for...in loops unless the property's key is a Symbol.

This is the code I'm playing with:

```
function Car() {
  this.name = 'BMW';
}

Car.prototype.year = 1998;


var bmw = new Car();


for( var prop in bmw ) {
  console.log( prop )
}

// name
// year

console.log( bmw.propertyIsEnumerable( 'name' ) ) // true
console.log( bmw.propertyIsEnumerable( 'year' ) ) // false
```

Why does `bmw.propertyIsEnumerable( 'year' )` log `false` when it is detected by `for..in`?

Comment: _"Every object has a propertyIsEnumerable method. This method can determine whether the specified property in an object can be enumerated by a for...in loop, **with the exception of properties inherited through the prototype chain**."_ ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable)

> Every object has a `propertyIsEnumerable` method. This method can determine whether the specified property in an object can be enumerated by a `for...in` loop, **with the exception of properties inherited through the prototype chain**. If the object does not have the specified property, this method returns `false`.

```js
var a = [];
a.propertyIsEnumerable('constructor');         // returns false

function firstConstructor() {
  this.property = 'is not enumerable';
}

firstConstructor.prototype.firstMethod = function() {};

function secondConstructor() {
  this.method = function method() { return 'is enumerable'; };
}

secondConstructor.prototype = new firstConstructor;
secondConstructor.prototype.constructor = secondConstructor;

var o = new secondConstructor();
o.arbitraryProperty = 'is enumerable';

console.log(o.propertyIsEnumerable('arbitraryProperty'));   // returns true
console.log(o.propertyIsEnumerable('method'));              // returns true
console.log(o.propertyIsEnumerable('property'));            // returns false

o.property = 'is enumerable';

console.log(o.propertyIsEnumerable('property'));            // returns true

// These return false as they are on the prototype which 
// propertyIsEnumerable does not consider (even though the last two
// are iteratable with for-in)
console.log(o.propertyIsEnumerable('prototype'));   // returns false (as of JS 1.8.1/FF3.6)
console.log(o.propertyIsEnumerable('constructor')); // returns false
console.log(o.propertyIsEnumerable('firstMethod')); // returns false
```

Source: [Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable)

Answer (score 1):

`propertyIsEnumerable` does return `false` ( an exception ) for properties inherited from prototype chain where as `for ... in` loops on properties inherited from prototype too

> Every object has a propertyIsEnumerable method. This method can
>   determine whether the specified property in an object can be
>   enumerated by a for...in loop, with the exception of properties
>   inherited through the prototype chain. If the object does not have the
>   specified property, this method returns false

[`MDN ref`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable#Description)